# What the right place to create a web service client for a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, savon

I want to connect to a web service using savon in a rails application, but I don't know where to start. I would like to have it encapsulated, not just code in a controller. Where is the right place to create it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could start with `lib/services` directory. In general, non-Rails Ruby projects contain all the code inside `lib`, so it's good choice.

However, code inside `lib` directory isn't automatically reloaded in Rails by default. But you could setup it with

```
# config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib/services"
```

Also, you should follow standard naming conventions (`lib/services/example.rb` should contain class `Example`) in order autoloading to work properly.

Comment: The autoload goes in the file loosely or inside the Application class ?TY

Comment: Inside `Application` class.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be like hedgesky, create a sub folder inside `lib` call `lib/third_party/third_party_name`.

This folder would contain any logic which would be needed to connect to your partner.

Then you create a service `services/...` which contain your business logic and will call the connector.

Finally call your service in the controller.

Like so, everything has his own layer. More then that, if later on you create a second app using the same partner. You could extract `lib/third_party/third_party_name` inside your own gem and reuse it.